# Interactive access to command using NSTask

Tags: cocoa, nstask, nspipe

I am using an NSTask to run a cli app that in interactive. Im using it to pull data over a USB connection.

I am opening an NSTask with an outline and error pipe but when I issue a command, it works, but spins the beach ball in the loop pulling data from the output.

I expect to be able to mash the - (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender button that executes the help command and get the output back:

```
NSTask *usbCommandTask;
NSPipe *outPipe;
NSPipe *inPipe;
NSPipe *errorPipe;
NSFileHandle *inFile;
NSFileHandle *outFile;
NSTimer *pollTimer;
dispatch_queue_t mtpTask;

@implementation AppDelegate


- (void)commandNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSData *data = nil;

    while ((data = [outFile availableData]) && [data length]){
        NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Data: %@",myString);
        }
    NSLog(@"Execution never gets here");

}

-(void)checkTask
{
    if(usbCommandTask){
        if([usbCommandTask isRunning])NSLog(@"Task running"); else NSLog(@"Task dead");

    } else NSLog(@"Task is nil");


}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {



    usbCommandTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [usbCommandTask setLaunchPath:@"/Applications/usb-debugger-cli"];
    [usbCommandTask setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/"];
    [usbCommandTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"-i"]];
    inPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [usbCommandTask setStandardInput:inPipe];




    outPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [usbCommandTask setStandardOutput:outPipe];
    errorPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [usbCommandTask setStandardError:errorPipe];

    outFile = [outPipe fileHandleForReading];
    inFile = [inPipe fileHandleForWriting];

     [outFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(commandNotification:)
                                                 name:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                                               object:nil];



    pollTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(checkTask) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
    [usbCommandTask launch];
    NSLog(@"Launched");



}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
    if(usbCommandTask)[usbCommandTask terminate];


}


- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {

    if(usbCommandTask){
    NSString *command=@"help\n";
    NSData *commandData=[NSData dataWithBytes:command.UTF8String length:command.length];

    [inFile writeData:commandData];
    }
    else
    {NSLog(@"Comamnd task dead");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[outFile availableData]
```

is actually a blocking calling there is no data or explicit EOF, so this will always block, instead I used:

```
data = [outFile availableData];
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Data: %@",myString);
[outFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
```